# Role="alert" in IE while using JAWS

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using JAWS to make our application accessible. We have a lot of modals and popups. I've used role="alert", along with aria-live = "assertive", aria-modal="true" with moderate success.

It works great in Firefox, and Chrome but surprisingly doesn't work in IE 11. I've tried a few different things by changing the aria attributes but have had no luck. Voiceover in safari doesn't read anything as well.

I'm pretty sure there's a small thing I'm missing but I'm not sure what is it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how does it not work? Is there any error in console in IE 11? And please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test. It's hard to locate the issue with only description. Besides, I find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296683/jaws-16-not-reading-alert-role-in-ie-11), you could also refer to it.

Comment: agree with @YuZhou, we need an example that will not work and what it is not doing correctly to be able to help, there are hundreds of things you might have not quite gotten correct. I cannot tell whether you are trying to create an alert or a modal at this stage, if you drop a code example in I will have a look at it for you.